# How do I store multiple values from user input into a vector at once (in c++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, input

For a school project I have to use code to decipher a line of numbers separated by commas.

For example, a user might enter this an input:

```
10,8.5,11,10.5,7.5,5,6
```

and using the provided key, this would be the output:

```
sputnik
```

I need to take the input above, and somehow get each of the numbers (inbetween the commas) into a vector, then I will be about to decipher each value.

I have used strings for the other ciphers (rot13 and rot6) but just strings alone will not work in this case, obviously.

I could easily do it one value at a time using a for loop, but I don't think that's what he wants.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `std::getline()` with delimiter `','` could be handy.

Comment: _" but I don't think that's what he wants"_ Clarify that with your teacher first please.

Comment: I can confirm that is not what he wants.

Comment: There are already a plethora of similar posts on StackOverflow.  Search the internet for "StackOverflow C++ read file array comma floating point"

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as this:

```
std::vector<double> data;
double value = 0.0;
while (my_data_file >> value)
{
  data.push_back(value);
  char comma;
  my_data_file >> comma;
}
```

If you *must* use arrays here's the equivalent:

```
const size_t MAXIMUM_DATA = 32;
double data[32];
double value;
size_t array_index = 0;
while ((array_index < MAXIMUM_DATA) && (my_data_file >> value))
{
    data[array_index] = value;
    ++array_index;
    char comma;
    my_data_file >> comma;
}
```